# How Component Did Mount works properly?

Tags: reactjs

I'm having a problem while running my react js project.
**componentDidMount** not working.
my react.js version is **`^16.13.1`**.
My code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../../Assets/Styles/common.css";
import "./settingView.css";

import Sidebar from "../../Components/Sidebar/sidebar";
import Navbar from "../../Components/Navbar/navbar";

import Setting from "../../Components/Setting/setting";
import { getERPData } from '../../LocalStorage/localSrorage';
import history from '../../Routing/history';

class SettingView extends Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    console.log("Setting");
    if(!getERPData()){
      history.push("/");
      console.log("Data not Found");
    }
    else{
      console.log("Data Found");
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default SettingView;
```

Here is the whole code for my component.
**componentDidMount** not working.

Comment: what is `getERPData`? Where is it defined? if it is a method of the component then use `this.getERPData()`.

Comment: Please post your full code and give more details

Comment: ```getERPData()``` is data from LocalStorage

Comment: i'm checking if data available or not
if not available then push the route to "/"

Comment: as you can see ```console.log("Setting")``` not even working

Comment: Add the code for the rest of the file to help us determine the reason why `componentDidMount` is not being triggered

Comment: @MostafaOsama i've edited the description

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, if you are using `React 16.13.1` you could use Hooks:

```
export default function SettingView {
   useEffect(() => {
      console.log("Setting");
      if(!getERPData()){
         history.push("/");
         console.log("Data not Found");
      }
      else{
         console.log("Data Found");
      }
   , []);
   return (
      <React.Fragment>
      </React.Fragment>
   );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By the way. I got solution for the whole problem. I just restricted the JSX on conditional rendering of local storage. and it worked.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../../Assets/Styles/common.css";
import "./settingView.css";

import Sidebar from "../../Components/Sidebar/sidebar";
import Navbar from "../../Components/Navbar/navbar";

import Setting from "../../Components/Setting/setting";
import { getERPData } from '../../LocalStorage/localSrorage';
import history from '../../Routing/history';

class SettingsPage extends Component {
  state = {  }
  componentDidMount(){
    if(!getERPData()){
      history.push("/");
    }
  }
  render() { 
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {
          getERPData()?
          <div className="w-100">
              All My JSX here
          </div>
          :""
        }
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
}
 
export default SettingsPage;
```

this is how all the things got fine